# Python imports for machine learning

Tags: python, project-structure

I'm switching from R to Python for new machine learning project I'm doing.

I found one code architecture which seems ok (image below) but I have problems with with implementation if I want to keep my code DRY.

[image]

So basically I have a piece of code (functions) that I want to share across different modules (namely `data`, `features` and `model`s located under `src` module).
That code in this case contains functions for loading and saving the data.

The problem is that I cannot import functions from upper module (for example if I had `functions.py` directly under `src` folder)

I could add separate `functions.py` inside every module (`data`, `features`, `models`) but that would defeat the purpose of me trying to create well structured project.

I assume I'm not the only one with this issue.

How is this usually handled?

How do you create shared module that can be used by all most deeply nested modules? (I'd like to import the same module into `make_dataset.py`, `build_features.py`, `predict_model.py`, `train_model.py`)

**EDIT:**

I also forgot to mention I use virtualenv and global space should not be contaminated.

**SOLUTION:**

So what I ended up doing was I added the following code to my top package `__init__.py` file:

`import sys, os
fullPathToProjectFolder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, fullPathToProjectFolder)
print('__init__ project packege linked: ' + fullPathToProjectFolder)`

So whenever you use anything from the main package or the subpackage it is automatically linked (because when you import main package then `__init__.py` file is automatically called). And every module can make it's imports relative to top package.

E.g: if `train_model.py` wants to import `build_features.py` it would do it like so:

`from features import build_features`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your project to your system path so that python can find the module.

This can be done within python:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, fullPathToProjectFolder)
```

Then you will be able to call your modules with

```
import general_functions
```

Comment: I also forgot to mention I use virtualenv and global space should not be contaminated. Does this work in that case?

Comment: Yes. This effects the path only temporarily, it doesn't effect other running python programs and is deleted when you close your program.

Comment: Correct, but if you place those two lines at the beginning of the file, then every time that program is run, you're good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `__init__.py` file in your directory would you make as a module. So `functions.py` or whatever is in the folder that you can call with `import`. I hope it works https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages